# Unable to import org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.IConnectionProfile package

Tags: javadb

I am trying to connect to  a `javaDB` using the eclipse `DTP` profile programmatically.

```
IConnectionProfile profile = ProfileManager.getInstance().getProfileByName("myprofile");
```

Is there a `jar` file that I need to add to the project?

Answer (score 0):

For connectivity within your eclipse plugin, you need to have the DTP installed then add `org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity` to your plugin’s `MANIFEST.MF` file `Require-Bundle` section.